# Supporting a device with different dpi across x and y axis

Tags: android

I am targeting a device which has a different DPI across x and y axis. For example while 100 pixels occupy 10mm physical space across the x-axis, 100 pixels across the y-axis only occupy 9mm physical space. In other words the y-axis on my device has a higher dpi by 10%.

So if on the emulator (AVD) i draw a circle - it looks like an oval flattened in the horizontal direction.

Is there a way i can support this on the emulator? How can I manage my layouts so as to have the correct aspect ratio on the actual device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I manage my layouts so as to have the correct aspect ratio on the actual device.

I don't know if that really works well since there is afaik no A/R support in Android but you could probably

a) fix the device
 b) use pre-calculated dip values in your layout xml that include the 90%
 c) subclass the layout (`LinearLayout` etc ) classes and try to cope with the 90% in there.